# How to use SharePoint Field in application page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am creating application page. On this application page I want to update some SharePoint fields in my List.

So I have created this in aspx file:

```
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">


    <SharePoint:TextField ControlMode="Edit" runat="server" FieldName="Size" ID="SizeField"></SharePoint:TextField>
</asp:Content>
```

In cs Page_Load I have this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Media Content"];
            SizeField.ListId = list.ID;
            SizeField.ItemId = 5;
}
```

But When I load the page I got Error.

But When I add to aspx this  (ListId and ItemId directly in aspx)

```
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">


    <SharePoint:TextField ControlMode="Edit" runat="server" FieldName="Size" ID="SizeField" ListId="7a00ae8c-9e8d-4762-81a2-a21b76a24ea7" ItemId="5"></SharePoint:TextField>
</asp:Content>
```

And Page load in cs is empty it works without any problem....

But I want to change ItemId and ListId dynamically in cs code....Hmm...Thank you

PS: I try also add initialization to OnInit or in CreateChildControls but without success. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you should be checking if the splist object does not return null.
Then you can create your objects and write them to the UI. Maybe using a hybrid solution with controls on both aspx and cs is not working out.